# GET 'today' data in Django-Filter/DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I'm trying to get the today or yesterday data from the current day using django-filter/DRF.

```
class SampleFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    start_date = DateTimeFilter(field_name='timestamp', lookup_expr='gte')
    end_date = DateTimeFilter(field_name='timestamp', lookup_expr='lte')

    class Meta:
        model = Sample
        fields = []
```

on my django-rest api url. when I get the data `start_date=${start}&end_date=${end}` for the dates of today, it returns zero data even it have in the database.

`"GET /api/v1/sample/?start_date=2021-02-02&end_date=2021-02-02 HTTP/1.1" 200 2"` it is 200 success but it returns nothing.

What's wrong in my code? please help. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a DateTimeFilter, not a DateFilter.

By supplying a value like "2021-02-02" - i.e. a date, not a datetime - it's failing to parse, and silently discarding the value and the filter.

Try either changing to a DateFilter, or passing a full datetime as the argument.

Comment: Thank you, i tried changing it into `DateFromToRangeFilter`.